# Set the src of an image with jQuery from a site that provides a different image with each refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

I want to dynamically load the src from [This Person Does Not Exist](https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/) for multiple img objects on the DOM.

When using the jquery attr function, every img object contains the same image. I want each object to contain a "refreshed" image.

I have successfully managed to get it to work using `setTimeout` but would prefer if I didn't have to wait for them to load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var time = 0;

    $('.imgDNE').each(function(e) {
        time+=2000;
        var obj = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(obj).attr("src","https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image?"+ new Date().getTime());
        },time);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a pure JS solution using DOM attributes :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var myImg = document.getElementsByClass("imgDNE")
    myImg[0].setAttribute("src", "https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image#" + new Date.now());
});
```

Use `#` at the end of the URL to "fool" the browser's cache without bypassing upstream caches

You could also try this trick here, by setting the `src` attribute to itself :

```
 myImg.src = myImg.src;
```

Comment: The actual classname function is `document.getElementsByClassName('imgDNE');`

Secondly, I am trying to populate an unknown number of objects, not only one.

I already implemented a cache fool in the original code `...?"+ new Date().getTime()`